# Search photo by tag in Picasa Photo does not work

Tags: python, python-2.7, picasa, google-photos

I am trying to get the list of photos tagged by a specific keyword but the API does not seem be working as expected

> https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/myid?kind=photo&tag=mytag

returns zero element , whereas I can confirm that there are many photos with 'mytag' because those are returned by Google Plus UI

> https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/search/mytag?mode=my

Similarly even the python API does not return any result.

```
photos = gd_client.GetTaggedPhotos('mytag', user='myid)
count=0;

for photo in photos.entry:
    count +=1
    size += int(photo.size.text)
print "Total  photos ",count
```

Even the feed API does not work

```
photos = gd_client.GetFeed(
    '/data/feed/api/user/%s/?kind=photo&tag=%s' %  (
        'myid','mytag'))
count=0
print "Found", len(photos.entry), " photos"
```